# How to import a yup schema from another file?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am wanting to organise my form code by placing schemas in separate files. I have noticed that when I export a yup schema, then import it into another schema it always fails. The schema data appears to be is correct (when I console log), however, the validation of the imported schema never runs.

Example:

*myAdditionalSchema.js*

```
export const otherSchema = object({
 someValue: string(),
})
```

*myMainSchema.js*

```
import { otherSchema } from "myAdditionalSchema"

export const constMainSchema = object({
  myValue: string(),
}).concat(otherSchema)
```

If I have all of these schemas in the same file I do not experience this issue, only when they are imported.

For example, this works:

```
export const constMainSchema = object({
  myValue: string(),
}).concat(object({
 someValue: string(),
}))
```

And this also works:

```
const otherSchema = object({
 someValue: string(),
})

export const constMainSchema = object({
  myValue: string(),
}).concat(otherSchema)
```

Is there something different I have to do when importing them? For context I am using this with Formik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this does work. There was an issue with `number().transform()` that was causing a bug (that I don't fully understand) when the schema is imported. That bug however does not persist when the schema is created in the same file.